# How many alpha and gamma rays are given off from nuclear waste uranium 235

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics

From the products of uranium 235 waste how much total energy / beta, alpha, gamma rays would be emitted from the decay of uranium 235 over its time of decay.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe information from one or more of these pages could help you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fission_products_(by_element), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_krypton, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_barium

Comment: There are not only Kr and Ba as fission products of 235U; There is a whole family of fission products. See "fission products".